# Editing xml files and preserving whitespaces and tabs

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document that would contain empty nodes that looked like the following:

```
<metadata territory="USA"></metadata>
```

After simply opening, then saving using XmlDocument, this line looks like:

```
  <metadata territory="USA">  
  </metadata>
```

When I set PreserveWhitespace to true, it converted the entire XML to 1 line, so this won't work.

These XML files need to keep the current formatting as much as possible. I know, technically, it doesn't matter which way they are written, they will be read the same way but I still need to keep the same formatting. I can't figure out a way to keep the nodes with no values to 1 line. Is there a way to do this?

The ONLY method that keeps the document in its original formatting is if the XML file contained 'xml:space="preserve"' in the header, but I am to leave the header as is.

The only thing I want to change is the addition of values. As I said, simply loading and saving a document adds this, so if you want to test, just try...

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Temp\test.xml");
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\test_02.xml");
```

Comment: FYI, it's not necessary to put "C#" in the title - that's what tags are for.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? Why do you care about the format?

Comment: This is my first post here, so I didn't realize I didn't need the "C#" in the title until too late. The reason I care about format is because this is a file for work that I don't initially create and when we send off the assets, the formatting needs to be the same as when it's created.

Comment: no, if it's just formatting, then it doesn't matter. XML doesn't care about "formatting".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Keeping the diff between the original and the edited version nice can be one reason (that's mine right now, at least). Changing one value in the XML to result in a full-file diff isn't always desired.

Comment: @Joey: often, keeping the "formatting" won't be sufficient to prevent small changes from becoming large diffs. It may be necessary to do things like sort the XML so that attributes are always in the same order, for instance, and the same with elements in cases where element order doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 8):

Just did the test and this works using both `XDocument` and `XmlDocument` by setting the `PreserveWhitespace` property.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xmlDoc.Load("test.xml");
xmlDoc.Save("testOut.xml");
..
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
xdoc.Save(@"testOut.xml");
```

**Input:**

```
<foo>
  <metadata territory="USA"></metadata>
  <bar></bar>
  <baz>
  </baz>
</foo>
```

**Output:**

```
<foo>
  <metadata territory="USA"></metadata>
  <bar></bar>
  <baz>
  </baz>
</foo>
```

Comment: As I said, I have already tried this and, unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I created my own test XML, it worked, but on these other ones that I am not creating, it puts all of the content on one line.

Comment: @Marvin You might want to check for differences in encoding and non-printing characters between your test documents and your actual documents. If you can normalize what is causing the actuals to fail to the way the tests are, that might be a solution. Ostensibly the people don't care if something they can't _see_ is different...

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Richard Schneider: I don't believe it's possible.  One possible solution is to take the output XML file and run it through an XML formatting program that normalizes the format of the XML file (you can probably write one with the unmanaged XML dom if one can't be found).

Since the file is always normalized, it won't change that much hopefully.

Comment: This is discouraging considering how great XmlDocument is in other regards. I'll keep messing with it and see if I can come up with something. Unfortunately, it may not be a 'clean' solution...

Comment: As I understand it, the fundamental problem is that XmlDocument is mutable - you can easily modify the parse tree in ways that cause the relationship between the source file and the parse tree to be unrecognizable.  So the XML DOM throws away the parse state.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using xmlDocument, I may recommend you to use XDocument instead (Framework 3.0+).

PreserveWhitespace will add a

```
<whatever> <...>
**</whatever>**
```

to each line while None will just close it like <... />.

I looked up for 5 minutes how to preserve those white space, but couldn't find it. There's something ommitting char(13) in the de/reserialization.

```
XDocument doc;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   //Alternative with .None
   doc = XDocument.Load(fs, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
}
```

and importantly..

```
 xmlDoc.Save("lala.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  When you load the XML document you lose formatting information; so there is no way that Save can give the same results.

Answer (score -1):

Why not save the file as a different format, then rename it back to XML after it's been saved. I would be surprised if it still gets formatted incorrectly. Not pretty but pretty easy.